# IP address range used by API Gateway HTTP Api

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

i have an app running on an ec2 instance behind an ALB, which is part of a VPC, now i am using API Gateway HTTP Api with http integration, which will call an endpoint of this app, since this EC2 and ALB is part of a VPC and not publicly accessible, aws docs are suggesting me to create a VPC link which will allow my API Gateway api to call my endpoint. Now the problem is i need to edit the inbound rules of my ALB to allow calls from API Gateway API, but what is the ip used by this API Gateway

i tried looking around existing posts, some posts are saying use some NAT Gateway and attach an elastic ip for this and use together with Lambda, i don't know why Lambda is required here and i want to know if it is possible to find the ip address range used by this Gateway Api. If HTTP Api of API Gateway doesn't use specific or set of ip address, can using REST Api help me to attach a ip range or specific ip?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-private.html#http-api-develop-integrations-private-ELB

Create the VPC link, assign it to your HTTP proxy integration and pass in the listener ARN

Comment: But what about allowing ip in the inbound rules of security group attached to ALB, will the ALB allow these requests or is it that, since we are providing listener ARN instead of ALB ARN, no need to add any new ip range in inbound rules